# Sentence from Morita's book about tangent vectors and integration

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading Morita's book *The Geometry of Differential Forms* and am confused about a statement made on page 62, which is in section 2.1 c).

He says:

"Then obviously

$$dx_i(\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_j}}) = \delta_{ij}$$

From another point of view, since $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_j}}$ is a unit tangent vector in the dierection of $x_j$, we can consider that [the above fact] reflects the fact that if we integrate the constant function 1 with respect to $x_i$ from 0 to 1 along the $x_j$ - axis, the value is $\delta_{ij}$."

Can anyone explain how this reflects that fact about integrating the constant function? I don't see the connection.

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of interpreting $\int_0^1\,\mathrm{d}x^i\partial_j$?  The $\partial_j$ represents the path direction as in path integrals from basic vector calculus which is why there is the "along the $x_j$-axis, and $\int_0^1\,\mathrm{d}x^i$ is integrating the function $1$ wrt $x_i$ from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: That would make sense...